# How to use Aws Temporary credentials in Nifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-token, apache-nifi

I have to use aws temporary credentials AccessKey, SecretKey and Token within nifi process to access S3 objects. AccessKey, SecretKey and Token will be provided by an Api call. How to use these temperory credentials in nifi ListS3 Object etc?

One of the options I found is using
AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService since this
Can I update the values of a controller service based on an API call?

[image: AwsCrentialsProviderControllerService]

Any other options that I can use in this scenario?

Thanks!
Ani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, we can leverage `AWSCredentialsProvider` controller service and NiFi REST API to build this although it may be a bit complex. Nevertheless, let's sketch it out here.

Whatever action you do on NiFi - updating the processor/controller service configuration, stopping/starting services/processors, are all making API calls in the backend. NiFi framework makes the call behind the scenes. And since we also have HTTP processors like `InvokeHTTP` we could build this thing. I could think of a something like the below:

1. Create AWSCredentialsProvider controller service and leave the configurations empty which effectively renders the component to be in invalid state. Note down its unique ID (UUID). Let's call it `cp-id`. We'll use it later.
2. Create your flow with your logic that involves `ListS3 -> <OTHER_PROCESSORS>`. Configure the ListS3 processor with the AWSCredentialsProvider we created in Step #1.
3. Note down the component ID of this `ListS3` processor. Let's call it `s3-id`
4. Create another flow using `InvokeHTTP` and configure it to your service endpoint which gives you your temporary AWS credentials. Use the credentials in and make another call with InvokeHTTP to NiFi server with `PUT /controller-services/{cp-id}` endpoint to update the properties
5. Make another call to update the run status of the controller service with `PUT /controller-services/{cp-id}/run-status`. This will enable the controller service which means now you can start the ListS3 processor which can again be done again using a HTTP call to NiFi server: `PUT /processors/{s3-id}/run-status`

Some useful links:

- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html
- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/3160/update-nifi-flow-on-the-fly-via-api.html

Comment: Thank you for providing/validating the approach on this.